# Before save image open popup where u save image internal or external memory

Tags: android, performance, android-fragments, android-studio

Actually my requirement is when i click on camera and save image on custom directory before create custom directory i have open a option menu where you save image internal memory or external memory and picture had save on that particular location is their which i have choose have any sample code please help us my need is in android

Comment: Yes. There is a lot of sample code on this site.

Comment: Its all here. You just have to find it. Google for it.

Comment: `i have done lot of google`. Not too much i think. Or in the wrong way. You could also read some android tagged pages here to find all you need. I also think you should rephrase your question as the popup needs to be before taking the picture.

Comment: ok sent me link and my requirment is open popup after taking picture

Comment: Show us what you tried so far ??

Comment: ACTUALLY  i try to create a demo i have take image from cemara and create a directory but before create a directory i trird to open popup where u save your image after that pop up option their have to option where you save image  phone internal memory or external memory and after select option their directory create and image save their

Comment: Post that demo code here.. By clicking edit below your question.. Add that whole code and we will try to solve the problem you are facing in opening the popup before saving the file..!!

Comment: when i take image after then one pop-up show who says the user where he save that image external memory or internal memory.

Comment: Share your demo code first.. Then i will tell you who will say that..!!

Comment: https://codeshare.io/w2oGM

Comment: see my answer you just need to open a dialog fragment inside your `saveImage()` function. Let me know if you face any confusion..!!

Comment: error still their n whr u edit

Answer (score 0):

Try using : [Directory Chooser](https://github.com/passy/Android-DirectoryChooser)

This will allow you to choose directories from your internal/external storage.

You can open it as a separate Activity or as a **Dialog/Popup**. More details with library + a sample is provided in the given link. Refer that and let me know if it helped.

I think this is what all you want.

For using that in eclipse you need to download these `jar` files. I have provided links below:

1. [com.github.frankiesardo:auto-parcel:0.3.1.jar](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.frankiesardo/auto-parcel-processor/0.2).
2. [com.gu:option:1.3.jar](http://guardian.github.io/maven/repo-releases/com/gu/option/1.3/option-1.3.jar).
3. [com.google.auto.value:auto-value:1.1.jar](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.auto.value/auto-value/1.1)

Download this `jar`. Put them in your `libs` folder. Clear and Build project. Errors will be gone.

Comment: when import library it can contain lot of error i think its studio project n i use eclipse

Comment: when i import it contain error i resolve max error only one error pending

Comment: AutoParcel_DirectoryChooserConfig cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: AutoParcel_DirectoryChooserConfig cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: Give me 10 i'll let you know after that..!!

Comment: error still their n whr u edit i import your jar after that error still their can u sent me link where u edit